# How to change / toggle React state?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to toggle react state after the button click. After clicking button Work From Office should change to work From Home and vice versa. But it is not working. What am I dong wrong? I am able to change only once. Can we do with if statement? What is simple way?

```
 ** React **
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import './ChangeSchedule.css';
    class ChangeSchedule extends Component {
    
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
        //    work:'from office'
        workFromOffice:true
          
        }
    }
    changeMyWorkPlace(){
 
        this.setState({ 
        //    work:'from Home'
        workFromOffice:!this.state.workFromOffice
        })
       }

        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <div class="schedule change">
                        <h3>Emplyoee Name: </h3>
                        <p>Today Pooja is work {this.state.work}</p>
                        {/* <button class="chageScheduleBtn " onClick = {()=> this.changeMyWorkPlace()}> Change My Schedule </button> */}
                        <button class="chageScheduleBtn " onClick = {()=> this.workFromOffice() ?'Home': 'Office'}> Change My Schedule </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    
    export default ChangeSchedule;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [a ternary expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to display content for each state.

For example:

```
{this.state.workFromOffice ? " from Office" : " from Home"}
```

Now this button should work as you expect:

```
<button class="chageScheduleBtn" onClick={()=> this.changeMyWorkPlace()}>
  Change My Schedule
</button>
```

[See codesandbox for fully working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-snow-bvp9x1?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

When the changeMyWorkPlace function created, it captures your initial state and uses it everytime you run the function so only works once. You should instruct react to use up to date state.
try this way.

```
   changeMyWorkPlace(){
 
        this.setState((previousState) => ({ 
        //    work:'from Home'
        workFromOffice:!previousState.workFromOffice
        }))
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as below. Just change the status when the click happen. And inside the button, use a ternary expression. Like so:

```
import { Component } from "react";
import "./ChangeSchedule.css";
class ChangeSchedule extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      //    work:'from office'
      workFromOffice: true,
    };
  }
  changeMyWorkPlace() {
    this.setState({
      //    work:'from Home'
      workFromOffice: !this.state.workFromOffice,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div class="schedule change">
          <h3>Emplyoee Name: </h3>
          <p>Today Pooja is work {this.state.work}</p>
          <button class="chageScheduleBtn " onClick={() => this.workFromOffice()}>
            {this.state.workFromOffice ? "Work From Home" : "Work From Office"}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ChangeSchedule;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the way you're structuring your state. You can make it really simple by just using one entry of the state - `workFromOffice`. Then, your click handler should care only about changing that state value to the opposite of what was set before. Example:

```
onClick={() => this.setState({ workFromOffice: !this.state.workFromOffice })}
```